# Python Pandas: Sort a CSV file depending upon the contents of its first column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, parsing, columnsorting

I have a CSV file with following content:

```
R10_0_yrdi_391    111    1.11    1.0    1.1    111.0
R10_0_yfyrn_9132    222    2.22    2.0    2.2    222.0
R10_0_hfeisk_3    333    3.33    3.0    3.3    333.0
R20_0_yrdi_391    444    4.44    4.0    4.4    444.0
R20_0_yfyrn_9132    555    5.55    5.0    5.5    555.0
R20_0_hfeisk_3    666    6.66    6.0    6.6    666.0
```

Now I want to generate a new CSV with sorted first column in such a way that same values corresponding to `R10_0` and `R20_0` values will be placed side by side:

```
R10_0_yrdi_391    111    1.11    1.0    1.1    111.0
R20_0_yrdi_391    444    4.44    4.0    4.4    444.0
R10_0_yfyrn_9132    222    2.22    2.0    2.2    222.0
R20_0_yfyrn_9132    555    5.55    5.0    5.5    555.0
R10_0_hfeisk_3    333    3.33    3.0    3.3    333.0
R20_0_hfeisk_3    666    6.66    6.0    6.6    666.0
```

Another catch is that portion of first column `R10_0_` or `R20_0_` is fixed but the length of the later part, ie. `_yrdi_391`, `_yfyrn_9132` or `_hfeisk_3` is variable. 
I have tried using:

```
f = df.columns.values.tolist()
df.sort_values(by=f[:1])
```

But its clubbing all `R10_0_` and `R20_0_` together.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: How working my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need `sorted` function by 2 parameters and change ordering by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
#create index by first column by position
df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
#create index by name of first column
#df = df.set_index('a')
a = sorted(df.index, key=lambda x: (x.split('_')[2:], x.split('_')[:2]), reverse=True)
df = df.reindex(a)
print (df)
                    b     c    d    e      f
a                                           
R20_0_yrdi_391    444  4.44  4.0  4.4  444.0
R10_0_yrdi_391    111  1.11  1.0  1.1  111.0
R20_0_yfyrn_9132  555  5.55  5.0  5.5  555.0
R10_0_yfyrn_9132  222  2.22  2.0  2.2  222.0
R20_0_hfeisk_3    666  6.66  6.0  6.6  666.0
R10_0_hfeisk_3    333  3.33  3.0  3.3  333.0
```

Or:

```
a = sorted(df.index, key=lambda x: (x.split('_')[2:], x.split('_')[:2]))
df = df.reindex(a)
print (df)

                    b     c    d    e      f
a                                           
R10_0_hfeisk_3    333  3.33  3.0  3.3  333.0
R20_0_hfeisk_3    666  6.66  6.0  6.6  666.0
R10_0_yfyrn_9132  222  2.22  2.0  2.2  222.0
R20_0_yfyrn_9132  555  5.55  5.0  5.5  555.0
R10_0_yrdi_391    111  1.11  1.0  1.1  111.0
R20_0_yrdi_391    444  4.44  4.0  4.4  444.0
```